# tr contains td with rowspan only didn't force new line with the next tr

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm writing a small program with table. And I found that if if a tr only contains td with rowspan and colspan attribute, then when I add another tr, this tr wouldn't be in the newline. 
Here's the code:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan='6' rowspan='2'>hello</td>
    <td colspan='6' rowspan='2'>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>hello</td>
</tr></table>
```

for reference, pls see the jsFiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/fvxjq1qL/
This seems really awkward, and I don't know how to fix this.
Many thanks for your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/uhq7o2sw/1/ this is the output I want (without the second empty  tags).  This small program I'm writing is for users to draw a table by themselves on a html page.(I need to get the html format table to generate a pdf report, so it would be much convenient for users to draw a table themselves and I don't have to write the html for them to get the data I need). When I tested this small program, I found this bug. If the user only wants to set a tr with 6 colspans and 2 rowspan(let's assume that he/she wants the td to be taller), then the next tr would be in the same line. So I tried to find a solution to fix it but with no luck.

Comment: Why would you do that? it doesn't make sense. Post an image to show the desire output that would like to have.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fvxjq1qL/1/ is this the one you want?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uhq7o2sw/ this is the output I want (without the second empty <tr></tr> tags.  This small program I'm writing is for users to draw a table by themselves on a html page(thus I can get the HTML table  format much more conviniently). When I tested this small program, I found this bug. If the user only wants to set a tr with 6 colspans and 2 rowspan(let's assume that he/she wants the td to be taller), then the next tr would be in the same line. So I tried to find a solution to fix it but with no luck.

Comment: @humble.rumble The problem is still unsolved. By adding empty <tr></tr> tag will cause other problems in my program and it's not the solution I want. I added it just to present to you that the this is the table layout I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you don't want to use this, but using an empty `<tr />` for the next (non-existant) row will fix this issue.

I'm posting this as an answer because I cant see it highlighted anywhere and this *is* an answer to this type of problem, it's what I've just needed to use.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='6' rowspan='2'>hello</td>
        <td colspan='6' rowspan='2'>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr> <!-- THIS LINE -->
    <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rowspan is set to be `2`. Therefore, the cell takes up the space of the cell below it as well. The second row then starts two positions to the right (past the cells with rowspan). That cell is then shown on the top of the table because there is no cell above it. This is because there is no cell that only occupies the top row. It can be more clearly demonstrated by this example:

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='6' rowspan='2'>hello</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what you mean is that when I set the td with rowspan attribute, it doesn't take up the space? Thus how can I fix this problem?

Comment: @EmmaWu Like shown in the fiddle, it takes up the space below it too. As to how you can fix it, I don't know what you're trying to do. Your presented code does not make a valid table.

Comment: Just as what I added later on my questions, I'm designing a table that will be set by users. Let's say that if the user want to generate a taller table cell and span it also. So he/she generate the table just as I put it. But the problem is, the next tr will be the same line with the previous tr. That's not what the user wants. So I'm trying a way to fix this problem but with no luck yet. May I'll try more with cell-display related attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot **span 2 rows** if there are **only 2 rows** in your table. In your case, it must be at least **3 rows**. Otherwise, it will take all two available rows and place the other rows to the right.

So, if you assume that he/she wants to generate a taller table cell and span it also,
you have to prohibit it and implement the following condition: *the amount of spanned rows **must be** smaller than the amount of all rows in the table*. Otherwise, it will produce an invalid table.

If it is necessary that the certain row is bigger than another, you can set the **height property** to this row.